# Making caret train rf faster when ranger is not an option

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, r-ranger

The website I am trying to run the code is using an old version of R and does not accept ranger as the library. I have to use the caret package. I am trying to process about 800,000 lines in my train data frame and here is the code I use

```
control <- trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv',
                        number = 3,
                        repeats = 1,
                        search = 'grid')

tunegrid <- expand.grid(.mtry = c(sqrt(ncol(train_1))))

fit <- train(value~.,
             data = train_1,
             method = 'rf',
             ntree = 73,
             tuneGrid = tunegrid,
             trControl = control)
```

Looking at previous posts, I tried to tune my control parameters, is there any way I can make the model run faster? Am I able to specify a specific setting so that it just generates a model with the parameters I set, and not try multiple options?

This is my code from ranger which I optimized and currently having accurate model

```
fit <- ranger(value ~ ., 
              data = train_1, 
              num.trees = 73,
              max.depth = 35,mtry = 7,importance='impurity',splitrule = "extratrees")
```

Thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify `method='rf'`, `caret` is using the `randomForest` package to build the model. If you don't want to do all the cross-validation that `caret` is useful for, just build your model using the `randomForest` package directly. e.g.

```
library(randomForest)
fit <- randomForest(value ~ ., data=train_1)
```

You can specify values for `ntree`, `mtry` etc.

Note that the `randomForest` package is slow (or just won't work) for large datasets. If `ranger` is unavailable, have you tried the `Rborist` package?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I can not upvote due to my reputation.